# Internet Explorer 9 doesn't display svg graphics and doesn't prompt to install a viewer

Tags: plugins, svg, internet-explorer-9

i have two machines. one with a "locked down" ie9 ... and the other that's not locked down by our group policies. 
i'm trying to figure out what ie 9 setting is preventing my locked down machine from prompting me to install an svg plug in. 
on the "open" box, when i try to load a web page that has an svg graphic, it asks me if i want to install a plug in. 
i've tried playing around with the following IE Settings:

- pop up blocker setting in the privacy tab.
- activeX filter
- disable toolbars and extensions when inPrivate browsing starts.

if anyone has suggestions please let me know.

Comment: This question should be on superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE9 might have SVG builtin...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/18/svg-in-ie9-roadmap.aspx

Comment: yeah, i keep reading that online in various places.. but i can't figure out why the graphics aren't displaying

Comment: maybe this'll help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx